# FB JS SDK setting iframe size to 0

Tags: fbjs, facebook-iframe

Our FB App was working fine then suddenly today we noticed that `FB.setSize()` is setting height to `0px`! Did FB break something or the behavior of `FB.setSize()` has suddenly been changed.

App Url: https://apps.facebook.com/memorablestatus/

**Update:-**

You will now find that the above url is working fine, since I have modified my JS to call `setSize` with explicit `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I had the same problem today, they have updated the js sdk and now the height is not correct, since I can't predict the correct height of my page I use jquery to do it, and since some things are delayed and loaded after a few seconds, I use a timeout :

```
FB.Array.forEach([300, 600, 1000, 2000], function(delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({height: $(document).height()});
  }, delay)
});
```